# Completeness of a dual space

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, dual-spaces, complete-spaces

I am working on a problem and i have pretty much a solution to every part ( total of three parts ).
I would appreciate it, if you look at the solutions and let me know if they are acceptable. If not, how can i improve the solutions?

To the Problem:

Let $(V,\lvert\lvert.\rvert\rvert)$ be a normed vector space with $V \ne \{0\}$.

And let $(V^*,\lvert\lvert.\rvert\rvert_*)$ be a dual space with : $V^*:=(A:V \to \mathbb R;\ \text{$A$ is a linear and continuous  functional})$

**(a)** Consider a Cauchy_sequence  $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}\in V^*$. Show that it exists $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n(z),$ for all $z\in V$

**(b)** Let $A(z) := \lim_{n \to \infty} A_n(z)$ Show that A is linear and bounded.

**(c)** Show that for every $\epsilon > 0$ exists a $N \in \mathbb N$ so that:
$$\lvert A(x)-A_n(x)\rvert \le \epsilon.\lvert\lvert x\rvert\rvert$$ for all $n \ge N$ and all $x \in V$

**MY SOLUTIONS:**

for **(a)** what would be an appropriate Sequence to work with?

for **(b)** i did similar to a to show that A(x) is linear. But i can not show that A(x) is bounded! I approach it similar to (a) but at the end i have $C = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1/n = 0$ which is against $C > 0$.

What is the best way to approach (c) using the fact that A_n is a Cauchy-set?

Thank you for your Answers.

Comment: It's a _normed_ vector space, not "nomalized"...

Comment: (a) is really meant to say that $\lim A_n(z)$ exists for every $z$ for every Cauchy sequence $(A_n)$ even though the wording is bad. You are not supposed to choose your $A_n$'s. With your interpretation you could have taken $A_n(z)=0$ for all $n$ and $z$!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The exercise for (a) says: consider a Cauchy-Set $(A_n)_{n \ge 1}$ and show that for every $z \in V$ it exists $lim_{n \to \inf} A_n(z)$. Does that really means, that i am not allowed to choose a set and work with it? How would you approach the problem?

Comment: MathJax: To get $\infty,$ use `\infty`, not `\inf`. Also use `\lim` to get $\lim$ instead of $lim$.

Comment: I'm confused. Since you have solutions, why don't you share them?

Comment: @Elmagnifico It's usually called a Cauchy sequence, not a set, but this is irrelevant. You're not allowed to choose it. In order to show that $A_n(z)$ is convergent, try to show it's a Cauchy sequence (in $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz the problem is that, i am working on this problem for more than a week and since i post it here, all i got are edit suggestions  and not any answer to my question. I appreciate the time that you guys take to help me improve my writing but it aint helping me with the question. So i decided i delete the part where i explain my solution with the hope that sb tells me what will the solution be instead of edit suggestions

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz I know what a Cauchy-sequence is, but i have no clue how to show part (a). Would you please help me out and show me how its done. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**(a)** Given a Cauchy sequence $A_n \in V^*$ and a point $z \in V$, look at the sequence $A_n(z) \in \mathbb{R}$. Thanks to completeness of $\mathbb{R}$, in order to show that it's convergent, it's enough to show that it's a Cauchy sequence (in $\mathbb{R}$). What can you say about the difference $A_n(z)-A_m(z)$, based on the assumption (that $A_n \in V^*$ is a Cauchy sequence)?

**(b)** Linearity of $A$ is the easiest part of the whole exercise. As for boundedness, it follows from the Cauchy criterion that $A_n$ is bounded. That is, there is $C \ge 0$ such that $\| A_n \| \le C$ for each $n$. This tells you how big $A_n(z)$ can be, and in the limit - how big $A(z)$ can be.

**(c)** From the Cauchy criterion, you should be able to check that
$$
\forall \, \varepsilon>0 \ \exists \, N \in \mathbb{N} \ \forall \, m,n \ge N, \, x \in V \qquad
|A_m(x)-A_n(x)| \le \varepsilon \| x \|.
$$
Just take the limit $m \to \infty$.